# Problem with flatbed cameras

Tags: 3d-view, camera, constraints, tracking

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVJgd.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVJgd.png)I am new to blender, I am currently doing a camera tracking on a bezier. But the problem is that when I choose the target for the camera constraint it becomes flat. And the view does not render anything. Knowing that before applying the constraint it works and that I apply 0 location and 0 rotation before constraining it. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (only keep the useful objects)?

Comment: What do you mean, the camera becomes flat? Apart from sharing your file the least you could have done would have been to show some screenshots of your constraint setup for example...

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for your answer. I have just added a screenshot with the camera, the view from the camera and the constraint. And I said that the camera is flat, it's to explain what the camera looks like in the left part of my screen.

Comment: please share the file, only the camera and curve

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-LjYdn0cgIu this is the link in wetransfer, is the.blend with just curve and the camera. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the scale of your curve (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>). Once done, don't forget to bring back the curve vertices radius to 1 (in *Edit* mode select all and right click > *Set Curve Radius* > 1)